# catkin error gazebo-ros-control missing on indigo plus gazebo7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install gazebo7 and then install gazebo7-ros-pkgs from debian as [this  instruction](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16092/remove-gazebo2-and-install-gazebo7-for-ros-indigo/)

I download code from github (tutorial code from book, mastering ros for robotics programming), and then catkin, it throws build error as follows:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "gazebo_ros_control" with any of the following names:

    gazebo_ros_controlConfig.cmake
    gazebo_ros_control-config.cmake



 Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "gazebo_ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "gazebo_ros_control" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  seven_dof_arm_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


    -- Could not find the required component 'gazebo_ros_control'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by

      "gazebo_ros_control" with any of the following names:
    
        gazebo_ros_controlConfig.cmake
        gazebo_ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "gazebo_ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "gazebo_ros_control" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  seven_dof_arm_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

It seems like I have not installed gazebo-ros-control package, though I think it is supposed to have been installed already by
previous install procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs
```

I check the packages by:

```
rospack list | grep gazebo_
```

whose result is :

```
gazebo_msgs /opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_msgs
gazebo_plugins /opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_plugins
gazebo_ros /opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_ros
gazebo_tutorials /home/shawn/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/custom_plugin_tutorial
```

**It turns out gazebo-ros-control package haven't been installed! Why?**

According to instruction of gazebo official, it is said that except for ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs, all other packages related to gazebo MUST be built from source.

Does it mean I have to build gazebo-ros-control from source?

Is it version-specific? Where can I find the right version on github?

[Is this the right link?](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros_control), if so, how can I git clone this package on this page?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262818/catkin-error-gazebo-ros-control-missing-on-indigo-plus-gazebo7/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I met the same problem with you. I use ros indigo and gazebo6. I installed the package "ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros-control" by use the command sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros-control to solve this problem.

---

Originally posted by [zyqzyq](https://answers.ros.org/users/30957/zyqzyq/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0